# How to make a graph using matplotlib with user inputs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, input, graph, spyder

I am coding in python on spyder and I want to create a graph. I am currently using matplotlib and making basic graphs but I would like to know how to make a graph where when you run the program a question for inputs of the data plots is asked so the user enters the data to make the graph rather then running the program and a graph already being made.
[something like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKgl8.png)
But i'm not sure how to do that. Any tips would be helpful!
Thanks

Comment: What you want is a dynamic graph, isn't it?
It sounds like this answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27118584/python-dynamically-update-a-plot-after-user-input

Answer (score 0):

You should at least show your attempt on this.But if you need an idea on how to do that,then here's a few information that will help you achieve that.

Ask user for input ( ) for the x and y values using a for loop .Make sure to stir them in a list by appending an empty list then use matplotlib to plot the x and y lists.